# System.ArgumentException : Value does not fall within the expected range in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am using caliburn.micro framework.

```
BlogDetailViewModel.cs
 private long _entryId;
       public long entryId
       {
           get { return _entryId; }
           set
           {
               _entryId = value;

               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => blogdetail);
           }
       }

       private BlogEntry _blogdetail;
       public BlogEntry blogdetail
       {
           get { return _blogdetail; }
           set { _blogdetail = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => blogdetail); }
       }

       protected override async void OnInitialize()
       {
           string s = await BlogManager.Instance.GetBlogDetail(entryId);
           blogdetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogEntry>(s);
       }
```

and BlogDetailView
I bind blogdetail to gridview using ItemSource Property

But i get Value does not fall within the expected range in Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0):

Unit you get a response from your async call to the `BlogManager` your `blogdetail` is not yet set. CM will renders your View before `blogdetail` is populated and is failing. Init `_blogdetail` in your Constructor.

PS: In c# the public proberties begin with a capital letter;